# PHP Web applications

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and I am trying to develop some applications so I finished one of such and when I launch it I got this error. The pc also has a newly installed operating system and the first thing I installed on it was xampp

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\FINS\adodb5\drivers\adodb-ado5.inc.php on line 347
C:\xampp\htdocs\FINS\adodb5\drivers\adodb-ado5.inc.php on line 348
```

Below are the codes to error.
Please help. Thanks in advance.
this is where the problem comes from but I also include the entire codes just in case it is needed. I am already grateful for the gesture

Problem code

```
{
    $errc = $this->_connectionID->Errors;
    if ($errc->Count == 0) return 0;
    $err = $errc->Item($errc->Count-1);
    return $err->NativeError;
}
```

Entire Codes

```
<?php
/* 
V5.11 5 May 2010   (c) 2000-2010 John Lim (jlim#natsoft.com). All rights reserved.
  Released under both BSD license and Lesser GPL library license. 
  Whenever there is any discrepancy between the two licenses, 
  the BSD license will take precedence. 
Set tabs to 4 for best viewing.

  Latest version is available at http://adodb.sourceforge.net

    Microsoft ADO data driver. Requires ADO. Works only on MS Windows. PHP5 compat version.
*/

// security - hide paths
if (!defined('ADODB_DIR')) die();

define("_ADODB_ADO_LAYER", 1 );
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


class ADODB_ado extends ADOConnection {
    var $databaseType = "ado";  
    var $_bindInputArray = false;
    var $fmtDate = "'Y-m-d'";
    var $fmtTimeStamp = "'Y-m-d, h:i:sA'";
    var $replaceQuote = "''"; // string to use to replace quotes
    var $dataProvider = "ado";  
    var $hasAffectedRows = true;
    var $adoParameterType = 201; // 201 = long varchar, 203=long wide varchar, 205 = long varbinary
    var $_affectedRows = false;
    var $_thisTransactions;
    var $_cursor_type = 3; // 3=adOpenStatic,0=adOpenForwardOnly,1=adOpenKeyset,2=adOpenDynamic
    var $_cursor_location = 3; // 2=adUseServer, 3 = adUseClient;
    var $_lock_type = -1;
    var $_execute_option = -1;
    var $poorAffectedRows = true; 
    var $charPage;

    function ADODB_ado() 
    {   
        $this->_affectedRows = new VARIANT;
    }

    function ServerInfo()
    {
        if (!empty($this->_connectionID)) $desc = $this->_connectionID->provider;
        return array('description' => $desc, 'version' => '');
    }

    function _affectedrows()
    {
        if (PHP_VERSION >= 5) return $this->_affectedRows;

        return $this->_affectedRows->value;
    }

    // you can also pass a connection string like this:
    //
    // $DB->Connect('USER ID=sa;PASSWORD=pwd;SERVER=mangrove;DATABASE=ai',false,false,'SQLOLEDB');
    function _connect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword,$argDBorProvider, $argProvider= '')
    {
    // two modes
    //  -   if $argProvider is empty, we assume that $argDBorProvider holds provider -- this is for backward compat
    //  -   if $argProvider is not empty, then $argDBorProvider holds db


         if ($argProvider) {
            $argDatabasename = $argDBorProvider;
         } else {
            $argDatabasename = '';
            if ($argDBorProvider) $argProvider = $argDBorProvider;
            else if (stripos($argHostname,'PROVIDER') === false) /* full conn string is not in $argHostname */ 
                $argProvider = 'MSDASQL';
        }


        try {
        $u = 'UID';
        $p = 'PWD';

        if (!empty($this->charPage))
            $dbc = new COM('ADODB.Connection',null,$this->charPage);
        else
            $dbc = new COM('ADODB.Connection');

        if (! $dbc) return false;

        /* special support if provider is mssql or access */
        if ($argProvider=='mssql') {
            $u = 'User Id';  //User parameter name for OLEDB
            $p = 'Password'; 
            $argProvider = "SQLOLEDB"; // SQL Server Provider

            // not yet
            //if ($argDatabasename) $argHostname .= ";Initial Catalog=$argDatabasename";

            //use trusted conection for SQL if username not specified
            if (!$argUsername) $argHostname .= ";Trusted_Connection=Yes";
        } else if ($argProvider=='access')
            $argProvider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"; // Microsoft Jet Provider

        if ($argProvider) $dbc->Provider = $argProvider;    

        if ($argProvider) $argHostname = "PROVIDER=$argProvider;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$argHostname";   


        if ($argDatabasename) $argHostname .= ";DATABASE=$argDatabasename";     
        if ($argUsername) $argHostname .= ";$u=$argUsername";
        if ($argPassword)$argHostname .= ";$p=$argPassword";

        if ($this->debug) ADOConnection::outp( "Host=".$argHostname."<BR>\n version=$dbc->version");
        // @ added below for php 4.0.1 and earlier
        @$dbc->Open((string) $argHostname);

        $this->_connectionID = $dbc;

        $dbc->CursorLocation = $this->_cursor_location;
        return  $dbc->State > 0;
        } catch (exception $e) {
            if ($this->debug) echo "<pre>",$argHostname,"\n",$e,"</pre>\n";
        }

        return false;
    }

    // returns true or false
    function _pconnect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword, $argProvider='MSDASQL')
    {
        return $this->_connect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,$argProvider);
    }   

/*
    adSchemaCatalogs    = 1,
    adSchemaCharacterSets   = 2,
    adSchemaCollations  = 3,
    adSchemaColumns = 4,
    adSchemaCheckConstraints    = 5,
    adSchemaConstraintColumnUsage   = 6,
    adSchemaConstraintTableUsage    = 7,
    adSchemaKeyColumnUsage  = 8,
    adSchemaReferentialContraints   = 9,
    adSchemaTableConstraints    = 10,
    adSchemaColumnsDomainUsage  = 11,
    adSchemaIndexes = 12,
    adSchemaColumnPrivileges    = 13,
    adSchemaTablePrivileges = 14,
    adSchemaUsagePrivileges = 15,
    adSchemaProcedures  = 16,
    adSchemaSchemata    = 17,
    adSchemaSQLLanguages    = 18,
    adSchemaStatistics  = 19,
    adSchemaTables  = 20,
    adSchemaTranslations    = 21,
    adSchemaProviderTypes   = 22,
    adSchemaViews   = 23,
    adSchemaViewColumnUsage = 24,
    adSchemaViewTableUsage  = 25,
    adSchemaProcedureParameters = 26,
    adSchemaForeignKeys = 27,
    adSchemaPrimaryKeys = 28,
    adSchemaProcedureColumns    = 29,
    adSchemaDBInfoKeywords  = 30,
    adSchemaDBInfoLiterals  = 31,
    adSchemaCubes   = 32,
    adSchemaDimensions  = 33,
    adSchemaHierarchies = 34,
    adSchemaLevels  = 35,
    adSchemaMeasures    = 36,
    adSchemaProperties  = 37,
    adSchemaMembers = 38

*/

    function MetaTables()
    {
        $arr= array();
        $dbc = $this->_connectionID;

        $adors=@$dbc->OpenSchema(20);//tables
        if ($adors){
            $f = $adors->Fields(2);//table/view name
            $t = $adors->Fields(3);//table type
            while (!$adors->EOF){
                $tt=substr($t->value,0,6);
                if ($tt!='SYSTEM' && $tt !='ACCESS')
                    $arr[]=$f->value;
                //print $f->value . ' ' . $t->value.'<br>';
                $adors->MoveNext();
            }
            $adors->Close();
        }

        return $arr;
    }

    function MetaColumns($table, $normalize=true)
    {
        $table = strtoupper($table);
        $arr= array();
        $dbc = $this->_connectionID;

        $adors=@$dbc->OpenSchema(4);//tables

        if ($adors){
            $t = $adors->Fields(2);//table/view name
            while (!$adors->EOF){


                if (strtoupper($t->Value) == $table) {

                    $fld = new ADOFieldObject();
                    $c = $adors->Fields(3);
                    $fld->name = $c->Value;
                    $fld->type = 'CHAR'; // cannot discover type in ADO!
                    $fld->max_length = -1;
                    $arr[strtoupper($fld->name)]=$fld;
                }

                $adors->MoveNext();
            }
            $adors->Close();
        }

        return $arr;
    }

    /* returns queryID or false */
    function _query($sql,$inputarr=false) 
    {
        try { // In PHP5, all COM errors are exceptions, so to maintain old behaviour...

        $dbc = $this->_connectionID;

    //  return rs   

        $false = false;

        if ($inputarr) {

            if (!empty($this->charPage))
                $oCmd = new COM('ADODB.Command',null,$this->charPage);
            else
                $oCmd = new COM('ADODB.Command');
            $oCmd->ActiveConnection = $dbc;
            $oCmd->CommandText = $sql;
            $oCmd->CommandType = 1;

            while(list(, $val) = each($inputarr)) {
                $type = gettype($val);
                $len=strlen($val);
                if ($type == 'boolean')
                    $this->adoParameterType = 11;
                else if ($type == 'integer')
                    $this->adoParameterType = 3;
                else if ($type == 'double')
                    $this->adoParameterType = 5;
                elseif ($type == 'string')
                    $this->adoParameterType = 202;
                else if (($val === null) || (!defined($val)))
                    $len=1;
                else
                    $this->adoParameterType = 130;

                // name, type, direction 1 = input, len,
                $p = $oCmd->CreateParameter('name',$this->adoParameterType,1,$len,$val);

                $oCmd->Parameters->Append($p);
            }

            $p = false;
            $rs = $oCmd->Execute();
            $e = $dbc->Errors;
            if ($dbc->Errors->Count > 0) return $false;
            return $rs;
        }

        $rs = @$dbc->Execute($sql,$this->_affectedRows, $this->_execute_option);

        if ($dbc->Errors->Count > 0) return $false;
        if (! $rs) return $false;

        if ($rs->State == 0) {
            $true = true;
            return $true; // 0 = adStateClosed means no records returned
        }
        return $rs;

        } catch (exception $e) {

        }
        return $false;
    }


    function BeginTrans() 
    { 
        if ($this->transOff) return true;

        if (isset($this->_thisTransactions))
            if (!$this->_thisTransactions) return false;
        else {
            $o = $this->_connectionID->Properties("Transaction DDL");
            $this->_thisTransactions = $o ? true : false;
            if (!$o) return false;
        }
        @$this->_connectionID->BeginTrans();
        $this->transCnt += 1;
        return true;
    }
    function CommitTrans($ok=true) 
    { 
        if (!$ok) return $this->RollbackTrans();
        if ($this->transOff) return true;

        @$this->_connectionID->CommitTrans();
        if ($this->transCnt) @$this->transCnt -= 1;
        return true;
    }
    function RollbackTrans() {
        if ($this->transOff) return true;
        @$this->_connectionID->RollbackTrans();
        if ($this->transCnt) @$this->transCnt -= 1;
        return true;
    }

    /*  Returns: the last error message from previous database operation    */  

    function ErrorMsg() 
    {
        if (!$this->_connectionID) return "No connection established";
        $errmsg = '';

        try {
            $errc = $this->_connectionID->Errors;
            if (!$errc) return "No Errors object found";
            if ($errc->Count == 0) return '';
            $err = $errc->Item($errc->Count-1);
            $errmsg = $err->Description;
        }catch(exception $e) {
        }
        return $errmsg;
    }

    function ErrorNo() 
    {
        $errc = $this->_connectionID->Errors;
        if ($errc->Count == 0) return 0;
        $err = $errc->Item($errc->Count-1);
        return $err->NativeError;
    }

    // returns true or false
    function _close()
    {
        if ($this->_connectionID) $this->_connectionID->Close();
        $this->_connectionID = false;
        return true;
    }


}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Class Name: Recordset
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

class ADORecordSet_ado extends ADORecordSet {   

    var $bind = false;
    var $databaseType = "ado";  
    var $dataProvider = "ado";  
    var $_tarr = false; // caches the types
    var $_flds; // and field objects
    var $canSeek = true;
    var $hideErrors = true;

    function ADORecordSet_ado($id,$mode=false)
    {
        if ($mode === false) { 
            global $ADODB_FETCH_MODE;
            $mode = $ADODB_FETCH_MODE;
        }
        $this->fetchMode = $mode;
        return $this->ADORecordSet($id,$mode);
    }


    // returns the field object
    function FetchField($fieldOffset = -1) {
        $off=$fieldOffset+1; // offsets begin at 1

        $o= new ADOFieldObject();
        $rs = $this->_queryID;
        if (!$rs) return false;

        $f = $rs->Fields($fieldOffset);
        $o->name = $f->Name;
        $t = $f->Type;
        $o->type = $this->MetaType($t);
        $o->max_length = $f->DefinedSize;
        $o->ado_type = $t;


        //print "off=$off name=$o->name type=$o->type len=$o->max_length<br>";
        return $o;
    }

    /* Use associative array to get fields array */
    function Fields($colname)
    {
        if ($this->fetchMode & ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) return $this->fields[$colname];
        if (!$this->bind) {
            $this->bind = array();
            for ($i=0; $i < $this->_numOfFields; $i++) {
                $o = $this->FetchField($i);
                $this->bind[strtoupper($o->name)] = $i;
            }
        }

         return $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]];
    }


    function _initrs()
    {
        $rs = $this->_queryID;

        try {
            $this->_numOfRows = $rs->RecordCount;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_numOfRows = -1;
        }
        $f = $rs->Fields;
        $this->_numOfFields = $f->Count;
    }


     // should only be used to move forward as we normally use forward-only cursors
    function _seek($row)
    {
       $rs = $this->_queryID; 
        // absoluteposition doesn't work -- my maths is wrong ?
        //  $rs->AbsolutePosition->$row-2;
        //  return true;
        if ($this->_currentRow > $row) return false;
        @$rs->Move((integer)$row - $this->_currentRow-1); //adBookmarkFirst
        return true;
    }

/*
    OLEDB types

     enum DBTYPEENUM
    {   DBTYPE_EMPTY    = 0,
    DBTYPE_NULL = 1,
    DBTYPE_I2   = 2,
    DBTYPE_I4   = 3,
    DBTYPE_R4   = 4,
    DBTYPE_R8   = 5,
    DBTYPE_CY   = 6,
    DBTYPE_DATE = 7,
    DBTYPE_BSTR = 8,
    DBTYPE_IDISPATCH    = 9,
    DBTYPE_ERROR    = 10,
    DBTYPE_BOOL = 11,
    DBTYPE_VARIANT  = 12,
    DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN = 13,
    DBTYPE_DECIMAL  = 14,
    DBTYPE_UI1  = 17,
    DBTYPE_ARRAY    = 0x2000,
    DBTYPE_BYREF    = 0x4000,
    DBTYPE_I1   = 16,
    DBTYPE_UI2  = 18,
    DBTYPE_UI4  = 19,
    DBTYPE_I8   = 20,
    DBTYPE_UI8  = 21,
    DBTYPE_GUID = 72,
    DBTYPE_VECTOR   = 0x1000,
    DBTYPE_RESERVED = 0x8000,
    DBTYPE_BYTES    = 128,
    DBTYPE_STR  = 129,
    DBTYPE_WSTR = 130,
    DBTYPE_NUMERIC  = 131,
    DBTYPE_UDT  = 132,
    DBTYPE_DBDATE   = 133,
    DBTYPE_DBTIME   = 134,
    DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP  = 135

    ADO Types

    adEmpty = 0,
    adTinyInt   = 16,
    adSmallInt  = 2,
    adInteger   = 3,
    adBigInt    = 20,
    adUnsignedTinyInt   = 17,
    adUnsignedSmallInt  = 18,
    adUnsignedInt   = 19,
    adUnsignedBigInt    = 21,
    adSingle    = 4,
    adDouble    = 5,
    adCurrency  = 6,
    adDecimal   = 14,
    adNumeric   = 131,
    adBoolean   = 11,
    adError = 10,
    adUserDefined   = 132,
    adVariant   = 12,
    adIDispatch = 9,
    adIUnknown  = 13,   
    adGUID  = 72,
    adDate  = 7,
    adDBDate    = 133,
    adDBTime    = 134,
    adDBTimeStamp   = 135,
    adBSTR  = 8,
    adChar  = 129,
    adVarChar   = 200,
    adLongVarChar   = 201,
    adWChar = 130,
    adVarWChar  = 202,
    adLongVarWChar  = 203,
    adBinary    = 128,
    adVarBinary = 204,
    adLongVarBinary = 205,
    adChapter   = 136,
    adFileTime  = 64,
    adDBFileTime    = 137,
    adPropVariant   = 138,
    adVarNumeric    = 139
*/
    function MetaType($t,$len=-1,$fieldobj=false)
    {
        if (is_object($t)) {
            $fieldobj = $t;
            $t = $fieldobj->type;
            $len = $fieldobj->max_length;
        }

        if (!is_numeric($t)) return $t;

        switch ($t) {
        case 0:
        case 12: // variant
        case 8: // bstr
        case 129: //char
        case 130: //wc
        case 200: // varc
        case 202:// varWC
        case 128: // bin
        case 204: // varBin
        case 72: // guid
            if ($len <= $this->blobSize) return 'C';

        case 201:
        case 203:
            return 'X';
        case 128:
        case 204:
        case 205:
             return 'B';
        case 7:
        case 133: return 'D';

        case 134:
        case 135: return 'T';

        case 11: return 'L';

        case 16://  adTinyInt   = 16,
        case 2://adSmallInt = 2,
        case 3://adInteger  = 3,
        case 4://adBigInt   = 20,
        case 17://adUnsignedTinyInt = 17,
        case 18://adUnsignedSmallInt    = 18,
        case 19://adUnsignedInt = 19,
        case 20://adUnsignedBigInt  = 21,
            return 'I';
        default: return 'N';
        }
    }

    // time stamp not supported yet
    function _fetch()
    {   
        $rs = $this->_queryID;
        if (!$rs or $rs->EOF) {
            $this->fields = false;
            return false;
        }
        $this->fields = array();

        if (!$this->_tarr) {
            $tarr = array();
            $flds = array();
            for ($i=0,$max = $this->_numOfFields; $i < $max; $i++) {
                $f = $rs->Fields($i);
                $flds[] = $f;
                $tarr[] = $f->Type;
            }
            // bind types and flds only once
            $this->_tarr = $tarr; 
            $this->_flds = $flds;
        }
        $t = reset($this->_tarr);
        $f = reset($this->_flds);

        if ($this->hideErrors)  $olde = error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR);// sometimes $f->value be null
        for ($i=0,$max = $this->_numOfFields; $i < $max; $i++) {
            //echo "<p>",$t,' ';var_dump($f->value); echo '</p>';
            switch($t) {
            case 135: // timestamp
//***               if (!strlen((string)$f->value)) $this->fields[] = false;
//              else {
//                  if (!is_numeric($f->value)) # $val = variant_date_to_timestamp($f->value);
//                      // VT_DATE stores dates as (float) fractional days since 1899/12/30 00:00:00
//                      $val= (float) variant_cast($f->value,VT_R8)*3600*24-2209161600;
//                  else 
//                      $val = $f->value;
//                  $this->fields[] = adodb_date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$val);
//              }
//              break;          
            case 133:// A date value (yyyymmdd) 
//***               if ($val = $f->value) {
//                  $this->fields[] = substr($val,0,4).'-'.substr($val,4,2).'-'.substr($val,6,2);
//              } else
//                  $this->fields[] = false;
//              break;
            case 7: // adDate
                if (!strlen((string)$f->value)) $this->fields[] = false;
                else {
                    if (!is_numeric($f->value)) $val = //$val = variant_date_to_timestamp($f->value);//***
                        // VT_DATE stores dates as (float) fractional days since 1899/12/30 00:00:00
                        $val= (float) variant_cast($f->value,VT_R8)*3600*24-2209161600;
                    else $val = $f->value;

                    if (($val % 86400) == 0) $this->fields[] = adodb_date('Y-m-d',$val);
                    else $this->fields[] = adodb_date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$val);
                }
                break;
            case 1: // null
                $this->fields[] = false;
                break;
            case 20:
            case 21: // bigint (64 bit)
                $this->fields[] = (float) $f->value; // if 64 bit PHP, could use (int)
                break;
            case 6: // currency is not supported properly;
                //***ADOConnection::outp( '<b>'.$f->Name.': currency type not supported by PHP</b>');
                $this->fields[] = (float) $f->value;
                break;
            case 11: //BIT;
                $val = "";
                if(is_bool($f->value))  {
                    if($f->value==true) $val = 1;
                    else $val = 0;
                }
                if(is_null($f->value)) $val = null;

                $this->fields[] = $val;
                break;
            default:
                $this->fields[] = $f->value; 
                break;
            }
            //print " $f->value $t, ";
            $f = next($this->_flds);
            $t = next($this->_tarr);
        } // for
        if ($this->hideErrors) error_reporting($olde);
        @$rs->MoveNext(); // @ needed for some versions of PHP!

//      if ($this->fetchMode & ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) {
//          $this->fields = $this->GetRowAssoc(ADODB_ASSOC_CASE);
//      }
        //***
        if ($this->fetchMode == ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) {
            $this->fields = &$this->GetRowAssoc(ADODB_ASSOC_CASE);
        } elseif ($this->fetchMode == ADODB_FETCH_BOTH) {
            $this->fields = array_merge($this->fields, $this->GetRowAssoc(ADODB_ASSOC_CASE));
        }
        return true;
    }

        function NextRecordSet()
        {
            $rs = $this->_queryID;
            $this->_queryID = $rs->NextRecordSet();
            //$this->_queryID = $this->_QueryId->NextRecordSet();
            if ($this->_queryID == null) return false;

            $this->_currentRow = -1;
            $this->_currentPage = -1;
            $this->bind = false;
            $this->fields = false;
            $this->_flds = false;
            $this->_tarr = false;

            $this->_inited = false;
            $this->Init();
            return true;
        }

    function _close() {
        $this->_flds = false;
        try {
        @$this->_queryID->Close();// by Pete Dishman (peterd@telephonetics.co.uk)
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
        $this->_queryID = false;    
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Chances are that you need to check if the `Errors` object exists, like you do some lines above with `if (!$errc) return "No Errors object found";`

Answer (score 0):

Yoy may use the function isset(var), for example:

```
if(isset($this->_connectionID->Errors)){
    $errc = $this->_connectionID->Errors;
   if ($errc->Count == 0) return 0;
   $err = $errc->Item($errc->Count-1);
   return $err->NativeError;
 }else{
   // CODE HERE ALERTING ABOUT THE ERROR
 }
```